# Why we use set in window handles in selenium and not list?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, collections

```
Set<String> AllWindowHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();
List<String> AllWindowHandles=driver.getWindowHandles();
```

Comment: Its `Set` only in Java. In C# its `List` and in Python `Array`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It prevents possible handlers duplication in the collection which may cause multiple invocations of the same handler after every event. List can has duplicated elements and Set can't

Comment: I think the same answer I have posted before you .. do you think its relevent to do so?

Comment: @ShubhamJain - Being first isn't the most important thing. As well as providing extra information, this answer is also better written.  That's why it got my upvote.

Answer (score 2):

The main reason in my understanding is that set do not allow duplicates while list is allowing duplicate values.

Answer (score 1):

Set AllWindowHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();
List Allwin= new ArrayList(AllWindowHandles);

We can use the above one, as set is unordered and list is ordered. All windows will have a unique id and the order of insertion is listed in a List.

Answer (score 1):

getWindowHandles method in selenium returns GU ID of all the browsers present at the moment, which are opened by the current driver. This method returns GU IDs as Set of String.

the return type itself is set so set is used